# How can I use Bash to perform a substring operation on backtick output in one line?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to get a substring of my parent directory. What's annoying is that I have to do it using two commands when one should suffice:

```
curDir=`pwd`; echo ${curDir##*/};
```

When I try to combine the two into one I get an error:

```
echo ${`pwd`##*/}
-bash: ${`pwd`##/}: bad substitution
```

How can I avoid use of a temp here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo ${`pwd`##*/}
```

will result in a parameter expansion like

```
   echo ${/home/yourdir##*/}
```

But you don't need command substitution in you case. Bash provides a builtin variable:

```
echo ${PWD##*/}
```

Comment: ürgen : Could you also demonstrate what to do if we don't have the convenience of a built-in variable?

Answer (score 1):

In this instance I would do:

```
basename `pwd`
```

In the general case there may not be an equivalent for `basename` but you can use sed:

```
pwd | sed 's,.*/,,'
```